# callback was already called! in loopback, in updateAll function

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback

I'm using the loopback, here while making the update call with list of objects in array.

I get in the callback is already called!

The scene is, I have defined the callback inside the loop, and in the first loop, it is get in called actually.

I am looking for the way where

I should update all list of object in query MySQL plan call.

```
    Inward.updateIsActiveDetails = function(data, callback) {
        var id = _.map(data, 'id');
        if (id.length > 0) {
          _.forEach(id, id => {
            console.log('id....:', id)
            Inward.updateAll({id}, {
              isActive: 0,
            }).then(updateresult => {
              console.log(updateresult);
   // callback(error); showing err with it... (callback already called)
            }).catch(function(error) {
              callback(error);
            });
          });
        } else {
          callback(null, {
            success: true,
            msg: 'No records to update',
          });
        }
      };
```

output:

```
id....: 3
id....: 4
{ count: 1 }
{ count: 1 }
```

appreciate for right solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my final and working answer.

Basically, updateAll query runs once and it will run as an inbuilt query

```
  id: {
        inq: _.map(data, 'id'),
      }
```

So, after running that it will update the respective row only! very interesting.

```
 Inward.updateIsActiveDetails = function (data, callback) {
    Inward.updateAll({
      id: {
        inq: _.map(data, 'id'),
      },
    }, {
        isActive: 0,
      }, function (error, resultDetails) {
        if (error) {
          console.log('error', error);
          callback(error);
        } else {
          console.log('resultDetails', resultDetails);
          callback(null, resultDetails);
        }
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

The callback is supposed to be called once, you're calling it in the loop, so it will be called **for each iteration of the loop**.  More than once.  The following would be correct if for whatever reason you can't use async/await.

```
Inward.updateIsActiveDetails = function(data, callback) {
    var id = _.map(data, 'id');
    var len = id.length;
    var resultList = [];

    // When you call this function we add the results to our list
    // If the list of updates is equal to the number of updates we had to perform, call the callback.
    function updateResultList(updateResult) {
      resultList.push(updateResult);
      if (resultList.length === len) callback(resultList);
    }
    if (len > 0) {
      _.forEach(id, id => {
        Inward.updateAll({id}, {
          isActive: 0,
        })
        .then(updateResult);
      });
    } else {
      callback(null, {
        success: true,
        msg: 'No records to update',
      });
    }
  };
```

With async/await it would be much shorter.

```
Inward.updateIsActiveDetails = async function(data) {
  const results = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    results.push(await Inward.updateById(data[i].id));
  }
  return results;
}
```